# Angular4+ Subject Keeps on Looping to Callback function

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm creating a blog using the MEAN stack and I'm running into a problem with my BehaviorSubject. I have a login page, a navbar, and a dashboard with some posts. When I login, I use router-link to automatically go do the dashboard. I also have a button for each post on the dashboard that uses router-link to go to that post. However, when I click on that button, the page dashboard disappears, but instead of going to the blog post, the dashboard reappears and we never get to the blog post's page.

For each component, I check to see if the user is logged in, because depending a slightly different view is presented if the user is logged in. I store whether the user is logged in or not in Local storage and I have a service that checks local storage. I make a call to that service in the ngOnInit method.

I put console.log statements everywhere, and I found out that when I click on the blog post, it checks to see if the user is logged in through the blogPost components ngOnInit (as it should). However, it also checks if the user is logged in from the dashboard component. It then goes back to the blogPost component and checks if the user is logged in again. I think this loop is causing me the problem.

For some reason, when I refresh the page and then click on the blog post, it works, but otherwise, after immediately logging in, it doesn't.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {

  loginBoolean: boolean;
  public listener = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  constructor(
  ) { 
    this.loginBoolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'))
  }


  loginTrue() {
    console.log("Setting login to true");
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
    this.loginBoolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'));
    this.listener.next(this.loginBoolean);
    return this.listener.asObservable();
  }

  loginFalse() {
    console.log("setting login to false");
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'false');
    this.loginBoolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'));
    this.listener.next(this.loginBoolean);
    return this.listener.asObservable()
  }

  isLoggedIn(location?: string) {
    console.log("Checking we're logged in from " + location);
    console.log(this.loginBoolean);
    this.loginBoolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'));
    this.listener.next(this.loginBoolean);

    return this.listener.asObservable();
  }
 }
```

This is the dashboard component typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NewPostService } from '../../services/new-post.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

import { BlogPost } from '../../models/blog-post.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  listOfPosts: BlogPost[];
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(
    private newPostService: NewPostService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.localStorageService.isLoggedIn("dashboard-component").subscribe((res) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = res;
    })
    this.listPosts()
  }

  listPosts() {
    this.newPostService.getBlogPosts().subscribe((posts) => {
      this.listOfPosts = posts as BlogPost[];
    });
  }
}
```

This is the dashboard component's html file

```
<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="createPost">Create a Post</button>
<div *ngFor="let post of listOfPosts">
  <li>{{post.author}}</li>
  <li>{{post.date}}</li>
  <li>{{post.text}}</li>
  <button routerLink="blogPost/{{post._id}}">Go to Page</button>
</div>
```

This is the blogPost's component's typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { NewPostService } from '../../services/new-post.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

import { BlogPost } from '../../models/blog-post.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-post',
  templateUrl: './blog-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-post.component.css']
})
export class BlogPostComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedPost: BlogPost;
  isDataAvailable: boolean = false;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private newPostService: NewPostService,
    private location: Location,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("We about to grab a single blog post");
    this.localStorageService.isLoggedIn("blog-post-component").subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("We're int the callback function, getting blog post");
      console.log("The response is " + res);
      this.isLoggedIn = res;
    });
    console.log("We're outside of the call back function, getting the ID")
    this.getId();
  }

  getId() {
    let objectId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log("We're outside of the callback function getting post: " + objectId);
    this.newPostService.getBlogPost(objectId).subscribe((post) => {
      console.log("We're inside of the callback function getting post: " + objectId);
      this.selectedPost = post as BlogPost;
      this.isDataAvailable = true;
    });
  }

  onDelete(post_id: string) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")) {
      this.newPostService.deletePost(post_id).subscribe((res) => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven’t read everything but returning the listener as an observable seems problematic but I’m not sure. Isn’t it creating a new observable every time those methods get called and shouldn’t there only be one observable associated with the listener?

Comment: I want to return it as an observable because I want to update all components that have their view depend on whether the user is logged in or not. Is their another way to update all components when the user logs in or out?

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Your code looks fine, the problem might be in the login component, can you share it?